# Cannot link the BLAS from Accelerate Framework during compilation -OS Yosemite 10.0.5

Tags: c++, macos, frameworks, lapack, blas

I created a matrix multiplicity code for an assignment but could not get the function working, so I suspect it is the BLAS lib not linked properly.
In OS X, the BLAS has been built into the Accelerate Framework, so in makefile I linked the lib by `-framework Accelerate`and in cpp I also include the header by `#include<Accelerate/Accelerate.h>`

During compilation, my error is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"dgemm_(char*, char*, int*, int*, int*, double*, double*, int*, double*, int*, double*, double*, int*)"
```

So I created a simple test code but I still get the error during compilation:

```
test_2.cpp:35:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'dgemm_'
  dgemm_(&TRANSA, &TRANSB, &M, &N, &K, &ALPHA, A, &LDA, B, &LDB, &BETA, ...
  ^
  1 error generated.
```

My simple test code is compiled with

```
 clang++  -o test_2.exe test_2.cpp -framework Accelerate
```

My simple code is :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cfloat>
#include <cmath>
#include <sys/time.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
#else
#include <cblas.h>
#endif

using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
 int n=10;
 int N=n;
 double *A = (double*) malloc( n * n * sizeof(double) );
 double *B = (double*) malloc( n * n * sizeof(double) );
 double *C = (double*) malloc( n * n * sizeof(double) );
 char TRANSA = 'N';
 char TRANSB = 'N';
 int M = N;
 int K = N;
 double ALPHA = 1.;
 double BETA = 0.;
 int LDA = N;
 int LDB = N;
 int LDC = N;
 dgemm_(&TRANSA, &TRANSB, &M, &N, &K, &ALPHA, A, &LDA, B, &LDB, &BETA, C, &LDC);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Accelerate` is not BLAS. You should link the BLAS library separately.

Comment: As I knew, in OS X, the BLAS lib has been built into the Accelerate Framework. Right?

Comment: A similar question has been seen before, [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615629/framework-accelerate-where-to-include-accelerate-accelerate-h)

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/BLAS_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/cblas_dgemm), Accelerate.framework prefixes all BLAS functions with `cblas_`. For example, the `dgemm` function is declared as

```
 void cblas_dgemm ( const enum CBLAS_ORDER __ Order , const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE __ TransA , const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE __ TransB , const int __ M , const int __ N , const int __ K , const double __ alpha , const double *__ A , const int __ lda , const double *__ B , const int __ ldb , const double __ beta , double *__ C , const int __ ldc );
```

Comment: Thank you! I was reading the documentation but I found a previous thread which makes me though the call is same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112135/understanding-lapack-calls-in-c-with-a-simple-example