# Calling BLAS from C in MacOS

Tags: macos, lapack, blas

I am creating a C program in MacOS and I would like to do Matrix-Vector multiplication.  My target platform is a desktop computer with multiple cores.  The development environment I have chosen is XCode.  I am not married to XCode; I do insist on coding in C (and not Objective-C or C++).

I would like to call BLAS / LAPACK functions.  How do I do so?

Apple offers a library called [*Accelerate*](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/701/).  However, the examples I see don't look like C code to me.  I'm guessing it's Objective-C, but I don't know.  Is there a way to call these functions from a C program?  How is it done?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple developer web site is probably showing the Swift interface for calling C functions.

Just include `cblas.h` or `clapack.h` and you should be fine.

Comment: clbas.h is not found when I include it.  If it were found, is there a Swift interface?  Where do I find it?

Comment: I don't have any experience with this. Try these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615629/framework-accelerate-where-to-include-accelerate-accelerate-h and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341127/cannot-link-the-blas-from-accelerate-framework-during-compilation-os-yosemite-1

Comment: `cblas.h` is in the Accelerate framework, so you should say `#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>`.